# Is it possible to restore a most visited website tile in Chrome 96's new tab, if so how?

Tags: google-chrome

I ran an extensive web search but found nothing, except maybe restoring the old tab looks from (very) old Chrome versions.

At the time of writing (12/2021), I think Chrome 96 is the latest version. It has less than basic settings and its new tab looks like this:

[image: New Tab]

[image: Settings]

[image: Chrome version]

Answer (score 0):

Click "Add shortcut", then enter the name and URL. If you've done any customization of the New Tab shortcut tiles, then you've implicitly switched it to "My shortcuts" mode, where you decide which tiles to have.

There is a "Customize Chrome" button at the bottom-right of the New Tab page. To switch back to the automatically-maintained "Most visited sites" mode, click the button, then open the "Shortcuts" section.

[image: The "Customize Chrome" button.]

[image: The "Shortcuts" section of the customization dialog. There are two large selectors, "My shortcuts" and "Most visited sites", with a separate "Hide shortcuts" switch below.]

Comment: This is nto the correct Chrome version I think

Comment: No, I think *you* have the incorrect Chrome version. Yours has been set to a different search engine, and likely has a nonstandard New Tab page as it lacks the standard Google search field in the center.

Comment: I just checked my version again, it is correct. I wonder how to fix it then.

Answer (score 0):

The tiles are created from your browsing history. When a tile is deleted,
the associated link in your browsing history is not deleted.

So, if you want to restore all the tiles you’ve deleted, you can do so by
clicking the "Restore all" link at the bottom of the New Tab page.
The "Undo" may help for one delete.

[image]

Comment: This is not the correct Chrome version I think

Comment: Yes, it seems that this version of New Tab has now been eliminated and the Undo option is gone - you will need to add the site manually. I'm now using the latest version and I have 10 icons in New Tab. How come you only have 8?